# Deserializing List<Guid> in ApplicationSettingsBase class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to save and restore a list of GUID objects with in a subclass of `ApplicationSettingsBase`. It saves what appears to be correct information to the XML file, but when restoring, the list object is null.  Here is the snippet of the `ApplicationSettingsBase` class and the property.

```
public class AppData: ApplicationSettingsBase
{
   ...

   [UserScopedSettings()]
   public List<Guid> LibrarySortOrder
   {
      get {
         return (List<Guid>)this["LibrarySortOrder"]);
      }
      set {
         this["LibrarySortOrder"] = value;
      }
    }

    ...
 }
```

When I save the settings to the file, I get the following XML (snippet)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
    ...

    <LibrarySortOrder>
      <guid>4b11c0e0-6bf2-463a-b71c-b4704e4a67a6</guid>
    </LibrarySortOrder>
    ...
</Settings>
```

I have tried defining the `[XmlArrayAttribute("LibrarySortOrder")]`, and `[XmlArrayItem("guid")]` for the `LibrarySortOrder` property, but it is always null on load.  What am I missing here?